# How to pass custom informations to Google Analytics/Google Tag Manager?

Tags: community, experience-cloud, google, google-analytics, tag-manager

I'm new with GA and GTM, so please be patient with me.

I'm using Salesforce Community, I've already added the tracking code in the Experience Builder and it's working, but I need to get some custom informations from the logged user and pass it to GA, for example, now  I have the user Id from the data layer in GTM as show the attached picture, but I would like to have the user name or department. Is there some way to get it? I thought to create a component and in Init method call an Apex class to search the additional information using the UserInfo Class then set the values that I need as parameters and send as custom dimensions to GA, but I don't know if it's possible.[image]